# How to plot postgres data on a map?

Tags: postgresql, google-maps, maps, tableau

I have a table which has latitude, longitude and some sensor data (data 1, data 2,data 3) saved in postgresql 12. I am running the database on ubuntu 18 virtual machine with windows as host. I dont want to run the database on windows at all.

The expectation is to somehow query the table ,get the data including coordinates and plot it on a map.
So far i tried :

1. Using tableau desktop but it does not support Ubuntu.
2. I tried grafana but the map does not have the required functionality
3. I also tried Metabase. It does not let you have multiple data on map, only one at a time is allowed. You have no control at all.
4. I tried PostGIS with qgis. But there is no simple way to achieve it. The learning curve seem to be very steep. I only need to plot.
5. Google map lets you plot from a csv. I do not know if postgres or any database access if available. It is very manual process to save the file from postgres as csv and then use google maps.

Please let me know if there is a better  approach to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: regarding #4, make sure to have a `geometry` column in your table. You can then display the layer in 2 clicks (1: connect to the DB, 2: select the layer)

Comment: I don't think QGIS has a driver to connect to a PostgreSQL database table and interpret two columns as X and Y coordinates. It can only do it through PostGIS and that requires your table have the correct PostGIS structure with a "geometry" column. If you tried to do this but failed it might be worth asking that question directly ("How do I convert a plain Postgres table to PostGIS?")  as a new question (if its not already answered).

Comment: PostGIS required you will need a geom field see step 3 here > https://www.kevfoo.com/2012/01/Importing-CSV-to-PostGIS/